# Make an "a" item of div not have the same css properties

Tags: html, css

I want to create a top menu navigation bar and I want to have my title in the left. But now when my title is hovered, it lights up and I don't want that. How can I have different properties for a specific HTML element? I just want it not to light up when hovered.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background: #F9F9F9;
}

.topnav {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.topnav label {
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  font-size: 16pt;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.topnav a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background: #ddd;
  color: black;
}


/* Add a color to the active/current link */

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #FF6138;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.topnav .loginnav {
  float: right
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="topnav">
  <a id="titleID" href="/">DDTech</a>
  <a id="homeID" href="/">Home</a>
  <a id="projectID" href="projects.html">Projects</a>
  <a id="contactID" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
  <a class="loginnav" href="#login">Login</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this rule:

```
.topnav a:hover {
    background: #ddd;
    color: black;
}
```

...to this:

```
.topnav a:not(#titleID):hover {
    background: #ddd;
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: And to make it only for #titleID?

Comment: @DavidDimitrie `#titleID { styles here; }`